# Maximize returns unevaluated even though there is a global maximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pure-function

I was trying to calculate the maximum of a gaussian plus a line, but Maximize return unevaluated:

```
In[8]:= Maximize[1/(\[Sigma]*Sqrt[2*Pi])*Exp[-1/2*(x-\[Mu])^2/\[Sigma]^2]+s*x,x ]
Out[8]= Maximize[s x+E^(-((x-\[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)))/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma]),x]
```

[image]

So I thought maybe it doesn't have an analytical form so I removed the line term but I still get no answer even though the answer is zero.

```
In[9]:= Maximize[1/(\[Sigma]*Sqrt[2*Pi])*Exp[-1/2*(x-\[Mu])^2/\[Sigma]^2],x ]
Out[9]= Maximize[E^(-((x-\[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)))/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] \[Sigma]),x]
```

[image]

I'm not really trained in Mathematica so I know I'm probably just doing something wrong, I just don't know what...

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

With the linear term included the function is unbounded, i.e. there is no global maximum. Even without the linear term, [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) does not work, so you must derive it.

```
f[x_] = 1/(σ*Sqrt[2*Pi])*Exp[-1/2*(x - μ)^2/σ^2];

arg = Simplify[
  Solve[{f'[x] == 0, f''[x] < 0}, x, Reals] // Flatten, σ > 0]

(* {x -> μ} *)
```

Or more simply for this case

```
arg = Simplify[Solve[f'[x] == 0, x, Reals] // Flatten, σ > 0]

(* {x -> μ} *)

max = f[x] /. arg

(* 1/(Sqrt[2 π] σ) *)
```